Convergence in distribution using the CLT
Given the sequence of random variables ${X_n}$, we define $F_n(x) = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{X\le x\}} \forall x\in R$.
Supposing $X_n$ i.i.d. and F being the distribution function of $X_1$.
Fix $x\in$ R with 0<F$_{(X)}$<1, study convergence in distribution of $\sqrt n \{F_n(x) - F(x)\}$.
In order to study this convergence I intended to use the Central Limit Theorem exploiting the iid condition, so:
$\sqrt n \{F_n(x) - F(x)\} = \sqrt n(\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{X\le x\}} - F(x)) = \sqrt n (\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{X\le x\}} - F(x)}n) = (\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{X\le x\}} - F(x)}{\sqrt n})$
Now knowing that it's possible to apply the CLT having
$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt n} \to N(0,1)$
To prove the convergence I would need to prove that the standard deviation of the indicator function is 1 and that it's expectation is equal to F(x) but I don't know if thats's the right way.

The CLT implies that
$$
\sqrt n \{F_n(x) - F(x)\}\to N(0,\sigma^2)
$$
where $\sigma^2=\text{Var}(I(X_{1}\leq x))$. To see this note that $Y=I(X_{1}\leq x)$ is a bernoulli random variable with probability of success $p=P(X_1\le x)=F(x)$ from which you can compute the variance.

If we define
$$
I_k = \begin{cases}
1, & X_k \leq x \\
0, & \text{other case}
\end{cases}
$$
we have $F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} I_k$. To apply TLC we need the expected value and variance of  $F_n(x)$. Then
\begin{align*}
E(F_n(x)) & = E \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} I_k \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} E(I_k) \\
& = E(I_1) \\
& = P(X_1 \leq x) \\
& = F(x) , \quad X_1,...,X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} F
\end{align*}
and the variance
\begin{align*}
Var(F_n(x)) & = Var \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} I_k\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2} n Var(I_1) \\
& = \frac{1}{n} \left( E(I_1^2) - E(I_1)^2 \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{n} ( 1^2 P(X_1 \leq x) - [P(X_1 \leq x)]^2) \\
& = \frac{1}{n} ( F(x) - F(x)^2) \\
& = \frac{1}{n} F(x)( 1 - F(x)) 
\end{align*}
Finally we have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n} (F_n(x) - F(x)) & \overset{D}{\to} N\left( 0, F(x) (1-F(x)) \right) \\
\end{align*}

This is wrong. $F_n(x)$ does not converge in distribution to $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ denote the mean and variance of $F_n(x)$, respectively. To see why, note that $F_n(x)\rightarrow\mu$ in probability by the law of large numbers. Since convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, you have that $F_n(x)$ converges in distribution to the Dirac measure with point mass in $\mu$. What is true, ist that $\sqrt n(F_n(x) - F(x))$ converges in distribution (Donsker's Theorem).

In addition, the notation $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} P_n$ where $(Y_n)_n$ is a sequence of random variables and a $(P_n)_n$ is a sequence of probability distributions, is misleading. Since you take the limit on the left hand side, $n$ cannot appear on the right hand side.

Thanks for the clarification Syd, I always get confused with the "$n$" inside the normal distribution. My professor would hang me by my balls if he had seen the previous things. Greetings and thanks for the correction.

Syd: Could you explain your application of Donsker's theorem in more detail. Thanks for your help.

@daniel: it may help (at least it helped me) to distinguish between the convergence result, i.e., $\sqrt n(F_n(x) - F(x))\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathcal N(0, F(x)(1-F(x)))$, and the resulting approximation, i.e, $\sqrt n(F_n(x) - F(x)) \approx N(0,F(x)(1-F(x)))$, which should be equivalent to $F_n(x)\approx\mathcal N(F(x), \frac1nF(x)(1-F(x)))$ by the invariante properties of the normal distribution.

It is, however, possible to make the notation $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}P_n$ mathematically rigor: define $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}P_n$ to mean $d(Q_n,P_n)\rightarrow 0$, where $Q_n$ is the distribution of $Y_n$ and $d$ is any metric that metrizes the topology of convergence in distribution (e.g., $d$ can be the Lévy-Prokhorov metric in $\mathbb R$).

@markleeds: the above statement is Donsker's Theorem; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem#Formal_statement

Thanks. I'll check it out.
